# Copy whole worksheet with openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

Please can someone give me an example, how to copy
**a whole worksheet with styles** (from rows and columns)
to a second worksheet in the same workbook ?
(in a new workbook would also be possible)

Thank you.

P.S.: I tried to do a deepcopy, but that failed on saving changed data cells.
Purpose is: I try to fill some worksheets with my data and the first worksheet is my template.

I was successful in copying the values **but only some styles**.
I am using the latest version of openpyxl, so please no 1.x methods.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Version 2.4 will allow you to do this: [copy_worksheet](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=copy_worksheet#manipulating-a-workbook-in-memory)

```
>>> source = wb.active
>>> target = wb.copy_worksheet(source)
```

For older ones you can probably copy the source code from [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/commits/61bfd644f09c)

**UPDATE:** You can't simply graft this code into **older versions** of the library

Comment: Worth pointing out that the version you refer to has not yet had a final release.

Comment: Another point is that this "copy_worksheet" function seems to be only restricted to the same workbook. (Source: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.copier.html?highlight=copy_worksheet "...from one worksheet to another within the same workbook.")

I wanted to copy the worksheet from a "template" workbook to another output workbook.

Comment: Specifying a target isn't working for me.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51128029/copying-to-a-specific-sheet-openpyxl-destination-sheet-ignored-when-using-cop

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this easily. The best approach is probably the one described in [bug 171](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/171/copy-worksheet-function)

Comment: thanks for cheering me up. finally i found python-relatorio to be more helpful. was difficult to find...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved using copy instead deepcopy. I found the solution on this [site](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/171/copy-worksheet-function)

I hope this works for you!

Comment: The reason to use deepcopy is creating a new object as copy of another, and not just a reference

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the links for the Openpyxl repository on @charlie-clark and @sam answers, these are not working anymore since the repo was moved from Bitbucket to Gitlab.

The updated link for issue 171 is https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `copy_worksheet` method does not copy [data validations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249). You can do this manually using openpyxl's `add_data_validation`. A full working example:

```
# Copy worksheet
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(source_excel)
sheet_to_copy = workbook[sheet_name]
new_sheet = workbook.copy_worksheet(sheet_to_copy)
new_sheet.title = new_sheet_name

# Copy data validations
for data_validation in sheet_to_copy.data_validations.dataValidation:
    new_sheet.add_data_validation(data_validation)

# Save result
workbook.save(source_excel)
```