# copy a worksheet in openpyxl

Tags: python, copy, openpyxl, worksheet

I'm using openpyxl (unfortunately I don't know how to find out my version number, installed it about a month ago) on Windows with python 2.7 and want to copy a worksheet that I generated using a template.xlsx file to a new workbook. The template has a single worksheet that I alter. I want to load it n times and copy each version as a new worksheet to another workbook. Could also be the same workbook ifneedbe.

I found some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101024/copy-whole-worksheet-with-openpyxl) which took me [here](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/171/copy-worksheet-function). The example doesn't work as it seems the `add_sheet()` method has been removed.

```
primary.add_sheet(copy.deepcopy(ws),ido+1)
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_sheet'
```

Also couldn't find anything helpful in the [API](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy whole worksheet with openpyxl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101024/copy-whole-worksheet-with-openpyxl)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid copying worksheets is not supported because it is far from easy to do.

Comment: That's unfortunate... do you probably know about another package that could do it? Could you point me to a place where it's described why it is so difficult to copy a worksheet as I can easily create an empy one?

Comment: There s no easy way. 
See https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/171/copy-worksheet-function for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with it as you. But, I could find out the way to solve.
The best way I think to copy Excel worksheets using Openpyxl and Python:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# workbook source = wb1 and workbook destination = wb2

wb1 = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
wb2 = Workbook()
ws1 = wbs.active
ws2 = wbd.active

for r in plan1.iter_rows():
    for c in r:
        ws2[c.coordinate] = c.value

wb2.save('file2.xlsx')
```

The FOR loop with iter_rows() creates a named list with existing filled cells. And the 2nd FOR iterates in those cells ('A1','A2','B1' etc). The method **.coordinate** can be applied to the cell(c) and extract the Column,Row like 'A1' as a string. If we add it as an index of the worksheet, we can set it as a variable. Then just get the value of the cell(c), the magic is done.
We can do something with data during the loop and after save it to the file.