# Copying sheet - Openpyxl: type object 'Workbook' has no attribute 'copy_worksheet'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to create a copy of a worksheet using openpyxl.

After researching I found this forum: [Copy whole worksheet with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101024/copy-whole-worksheet-with-openpyxl)

Here is the documentation for copy_worksheet: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=copy_worksheet#manipulating-a-workbook-in-memory

I tried using the code shown and it created this error:

`Atrribute Error: type object 'Workbook' has no attribute 'copy_worksheet'`

Here is the code i used:

```
wb = load_workbook(input.xlsx)

wb.create_sheet(new_sheet)

source = wb.get_sheet_by_name(original_sheet)
target = wb.copy_worksheet(new_sheet)

wb.save(input.xlsx)
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: What version of openpyxl do you have?

Comment: `import openpyxl; openpyxl.__version__`

Comment: I am using version 2.4

Comment: Hm, that should have `copy_worksheet`

Comment: I am using xlsx not xls that was a mistake in the code

Comment: could it be a mistake with get sheet by name?

Comment: The error doesn't indicate that. I'm trying with openpyxl 2.3 and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I am running 2.4 but not 2.4-b1

Comment: How did you install openpyxl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have figured out the answer.

I was using version 2.4 but to be precise I was running version: openpyxl 2.4.0-a1.

The copy_worksheet function was added as of version: openpyxl 2.4.0-b1

Here is the documentation for 2.4.0-a1: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Here is the documentation for 2.4.0-b1: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Thanks for everyone that helped!