# Copying to a specific sheet: openpyxl - destination sheet ignored when using copy_worksheet

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37948636/1059398) and [these documents](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/tutorial.html) I tried to specify a `source` and `target` sheet to write to, but when I do, the results are the same as if I hadn't specified a target:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
wb = load_workbook('MyFile.xlsx')
ws = 'Sheet1'


idx = book.index(ws)
new_ws = 'Test'
book.create_sheet(new_ws, idx+1)
source = book[ws]
target = book[new_ws]
target = book.copy_worksheet(source)
wb.save('Output.xlsx')
```

vs

```
source = book[ws]
book.copy_worksheet(source)
wb.save('Output.xlsx')
```

Both result in a new worksheet called `Sheet1 Copy` added to the end of the workbook. **How to a copy a sheet into another empty sheet, or specific location within the workbook?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# new copied sheet was assigned to target
target = wb.copy_worksheet(wb.source_sheet)

# now just change the name to desired one
target.title = desired_name
```