# want to add worksheet from one workbook in to another workbook using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am pretty sure there is an easier way than how i am doing it, I just have two workbooks and a single sheet in each work book,

does anyone have any any suggestions?

```
import openpyxl as xl
 
path1 = 'C:\\Users\\path\\test1.xlsx'  path2 ='C:\\Users\\path\\test2.xlsx'
 
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path1) ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
 
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=path2) ws2 =
wb2.create_sheet(ws1.title)
 
for row in ws1:
    for cell in row:
        ws2[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
 
wb2.save(path2)
```

The above code works for me, however it does not copy the format. just the cell values. I need formatting of the reports to be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy worksheet from one workbook to another one using Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344041/copy-worksheet-from-one-workbook-to-another-one-using-openpyxl)

Comment: You have to do it row by row, cell by cell.

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active
wb2 = Workbook() #or load_workbook
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2 = ws
```

Edit:

Above doesn’t copy anything, this link shows how
[Copy whole worksheet with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101024/copy-whole-worksheet-with-openpyxl)

Comment: This doesn't copy anything.

Comment: You are right, tried it right now. Check this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101024/copy-whole-worksheet-with-openpyxl

Comment: This doesn't copy anything, its just replacing worksheet that too within same workbook.