# Deepcopy of openpyxl workbook object

Tags: python, openpyxl

I was wondering if there's a way to create a deep copy of a workbook object that's created using the `load_workbook` method.

I want to create a process like this (this project will be in a Jypter Notebook):

```py
  #Cell 1
  
  import openpyxl

  #Cell 2
  
  wb1 = load_workbook("c:\temp\"abc123.xlsm", keep_vba=True) #This file is large and takes several minutes to load
  
  #Cell 3
  
  wb2 = wb1 #This doesn't create a deep copy but I would like something that creates a deep copy
  
  #Cell 4
  
  #Changes to wb2 happen here e.g. sheets get deleted. I would like to go back and rerun cell 2 so that I can reuse the wb1 variable without needing to load the file again.
```

Comment: Deep copy does not work but this question has an answer that might be [suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58198355/13664137) for your needs.

Comment: @moken I found that post earlier as well but I was not able to get it to work. I think the code in the answer is incomplete

Comment: I've never tried it but I know the concept is feasible as in you can load a workbook into Openpyxl from a BytesIO object. Anyway can you give some more detail on why you want to do this. Deep copy may not be an option but there may be something else that could suit.

Comment: You should continue the discussion on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a quick test with an xlsx file using an IDE.
This resulted in two new xlsx files from the original sheets and one has the the new sheet 'newsheet' with "hello" in cell 'B10' and the other with the new sheet 'Sheet10' and 'Hello There" in cell 'E10'.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from io import BytesIO


file = 'foo.xlsx'

with open(file, "rb") as fh:
    wb_data = BytesIO(fh.read())
    wb1 = load_workbook(wb_data)
    wb2 = load_workbook(wb_data)

    wb1.create_sheet('newsheet')
    wb2.create_sheet('Sheet10')

    ws1 = wb1['newsheet']
    ws2 = wb2['Sheet10']

    ws1.cell(10, 2).value = "Hello"
    ws2.cell(10, 5).value = "Hello There"

    wb1.save('save1.xlsx')
    wb2.save('save2.xlsx')
```

Comment: I had initially thought this solution worked because when I ran it the memory signatures of `wb1` and `wb2` were different. Upon further inspection, it looks like the reason for the different memory signatures is because `load_workbook()` is called twice. Using `with open(file, "rb") as fh:
    wb_data = BytesIO(fh.read())` appears to have no impact on performance (it may actually make performance worse). Thanks for taking the time to put together your answer however.

Comment: OK worth a look anyway