# How can I add an existing workbook sheet to another existing workbook with openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to create an new excel that contains the first sheet of a list of excel files.

I tried the following but of course line `wb.create_sheet(sheet)` doesn't work.

```
wb = Workbook('new.xlsx')

for i in range(len(file_list)):
    excel = load_workbook(file_list[i], read_only=False)
    sheet = excel[excel.sheetnames[0]]
    sheet.Name = tab_names_list[i]

    wb.create_sheet(sheet)


wb.save('new.xlsx')
```

At the same time replacing   `wb.create_sheet(sheet)` with `wb.copy_worksheet(sheet)` gives the error `ValueError: Cannot copy worksheets in read-only or write-only mode`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy whole worksheet with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101024/copy-whole-worksheet-with-openpyxl)

Comment: No, because I get `ValueError: Cannot copy worksheets in read-only or write-only mode
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not work for you but this is what I use in a similar application. It does require pandas dataframes, I'm not sure if you're using them or not.

```
file_list = [file_1, file_2]
sheet_names = ['file1_name', 'file2_name']

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("workbook_name.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

for file, s_names in zip(file_list, sheet_names):
    file.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s_names)
writer.save()
```

Comment: This works for me, although it is not an openpyxl solution. Thanks